# Reducing network requests for RSpec controller specs, how to set headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running a Rails 5 JSON API server. I have some controller specs written, but I' noticing that they are taking a really long time to run, and I'm looking for a way to optimize.

One way I've read about is to reduce the number of network requests by essentially making the GET/POST requests in a `before(:all)` or `before(:context)` block, and then having the subsequent `it` statements test the response from the single network request.

One issue I'm running into is that within my `before(:context)` block, I don't seem to have access to modify the request headers.  For example, currently it my code looks like:

```
before(:each) do
  add_authorization_header
  get :index
end
```

where `add_authorization_header` looks like:

```
request.headers['Authorization'] =
"Token token=#{some_authorization_token)}"
```

but when I chance `before(:each)` to `before(:context)` I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `headers' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a way to set the request headers within a `before(:context)` block?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no access to the request object inside the example group. Try:

```
before(:context)
  headers = { "Authorization" => "Token token=#{some_authorization_token)}" }
  get :index, params: {}, headers: headers
end
```

Comment: even better, let `headers` be a let variable you can override in your individual contexts.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  I get the following error:
`ArgumentError: unknown keyword: headers`